# hostapd + Ubuntu 14.04 Driver Issue for TL-WN725N v2

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, hostapd

I recently purchased a TL-WN725N v2 usb dongle so that it may be used for my Ubuntu virtual machine. My Ubuntu installation seemed to install the correct drivers when plugging in the usb dongle (rtl8188eu). I set up a pretty simple hostapd.conf file and when I try to start hostapd, I get this error:

```
Configuration file: hostapd.conf
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

My lshw looks like this:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:1
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: c4:6e:1f:12:41:ac
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=10.131.5.248 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

and iwconfig looks like this:

```
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.427 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

My problem seems similar to this post: [TL-WN725N Access-Point on ArchLinux + Hostapd](https://superuser.com/questions/761029/tl-wn725n-access-point-on-archlinux-hostapd)

Although I'm not really sure what the OP (@ochurlaud) did to get their adapter working on Raspberry PI.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/939140/283507) on the post you mentioned, I hope it'll help.